# Using Excel VBA code to send a POST and retrieve data

Tags: excel, vba, post

What VBA code would allow me to send a POST request (in a asp search box) and then  to retrieve data between a `<span id="xxx"></span>` tag? (in the resulting page)

I have the following code that simulates a search request in the page:

```
 Dim Site As Object
 Set Site = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
 Dim QNUMBER As String
 Dim URL As String

 URL = "apps/inventory/Default.aspx" 'local website
 QNUMBER = textBox_Scan.Text
 Site.navigate URL
 While Site.busy
 Wend
 Dim oHTMLDoc As Object
 Set oHTMLDoc = Site.document

 oHTMLDoc.getElementById("input_search").Value = QNUMBER
 oHTMLDoc.getElementById("btn_search").Click
```

It doesnt feel "clean" to do it that way and I feel that sending a POST request would be more appropriate.

Thanks.

[edit]

This is the form code

```
 <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
```

The input text id

```
id="input_search"
```

The submit button code

```
id="btn_search"
```

and I'd like to get data from `<span id="warranty">36 month</span>` and `<span id="budget">500$</span>`

Comment: I can't go to the URL. If the problem is just `HTTP POST` and `response`, I can give answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to mention that the website is local, I have edited my post with the form code and id of the things I need

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Sub macroPOST()
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = "[Your URL]"
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    objHTTP.Send ("id=dddaaa&pwd=1234[Your request parameters]")

    replyTXT = objHTTP.responseText

    If objHTTP.Status = "200" Then 'success
        MsgBox replyTXT
    Else
        'Do something
    End If
End Sub
```

It works on my Excel, thank you for reading carefully.